# Unable to post a new record through fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

I now have a problem with posting a record through fiddler. My code is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddStudent(Student s)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=PALLAVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Students (Roll_Number,FirstName,LastName,Class,Gender) Values (@Roll_Number,@FirstName,@LastName,@Class,@Gender)";
    sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roll_Number", s.Roll_Number);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", s.FirstName);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", s.LastName);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", s.Class);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", s.Gender);

    myConnection.Open();
    int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

When I run this on fiddler, I am getting a NullException. The response body is not being excepted by the code. The response body is in JSON format. Image as below:

[image]

**EDIT**
This is the error I am getting (image).

[image]

Comment: try to use `public void AddStudent([FromBody]Student s)`

Comment: Are you able to debug the service when the post request is made from Fiddler? Check if there is any exception when your API is trying to process

Comment: Since you are not using stored procedures (which I would recommend) you should take a peek at this article about AddWithValue. It can sometimes get datatypes wrong with pass through parameterized queries like this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter:

```
public void AddStudent([FromBody]Student s)
```

In this example, Web API will use a media-type formatter to read the value of name from the request body. Here is an example client request.

```
POST http://localhost:5076/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5076
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 7

"{Students}"
```

When a parameter has `[FromBody]`, Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).

Comment: Thank you. Set the parameter with [FromBody]. Working now.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 2):

I would set the Content-Type header as well in Fiddler

Content-Type: application/json